# Why iterate each digit in a number and find evenly divided digits not working?

Tags: c, arrays, loops, if-statement

I am writing a code in which a input is taken to run some no of test case and in each test case we have to iterate the number through each number and we have to divide it with the initial number taken and if it gives remainder 0 then we need to increment the count otherwise we need not increment the count and at last we will print the count.

---

> The number 12 is broken into two digits, 1 and 2. When 12 is divided
>   by either of those digits, the calculation's remainder is 0; thus, the
>   number of evenly-divisible digits in 12 is 2

Compiler Message

> Floating Point Exception

The code is given below and when running in a c compiler the program abruptly stops after taking the input.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(){
    int t; 
    int n[t],b,rem;
        int count =0;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < t; a0++){

        scanf("%d",&n[a0]);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
        b =n[i];
        while (n[i]) {
            rem = n[i] % 10;
            if(b%rem == 0)
                count++;

             n[i] = n[i] / 10;

         }
        printf("%d\n",count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an array of a given size before the size being set.
Another error (logical one), is that you didn't reset the counter for each number.
Your initial problem, is that you didn't pay attention of division by 0.
This may be a solution:

```
int main(){
  int t; 
  scanf("%d",&t);
  int n[t];
  for (int a0=0; a0<t; a0++){
    scanf("%d",&n[a0]);
  }
  for (int i=0; i<t; i++){
    int count = 0;
    int b=n[i];
    while (n[i]) {
      int rem = n[i] % 10;
      if (rem!=0 && b%rem==0)
        count++;
      n[i] = n[i] / 10;
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code, at the point you're writing `int n[t]`, `t` is not initialized. As the initial value of an unitialized automatic local variable is indeterminate and using that invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), so your code exhibits UB.

You need to move the definition of `int n[t]` *after* you *successfully* scan the value of `t` from user.

After that, from the property of `%` operator, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.5.6, (*emphais mine*)

> The result of the `/` operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the
>   second; the result of the `%` operator is the remainder. **In both operations, if the value of
>   the second operand is zero, the behavior is undefined.**

so, you need to make sure, `rem` is not `0` while doing `if(b%rem == 0)`. You should put a check on `rem != 0 && ....` to avoid this scenario.

That said, just a suggestion: VLAs are not the mandatory part of standard C anymore (`C11` onwards), so you can make use of a pointer and allocate dynamic memory using [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) and family.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Updated with relevant details.

Comment: "VLAs are not the part of standard C anymore" is incorrect.  _variable length array_ are well defined in C11 §6.7.6.2 and part of the standard.  What has changed from C99 is that implementation is not required. See `__STDC_NO_VLA__`